# Detect when there is no suitable activity in chooser intent

Tags: android, android-intent

My app creates an intent, and it then creates a [chooser intent](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) from it. If there is no app to handle the intent, the chooser intent creates a dialog to inform the user. I would like my app to get notified of this fact, either with an exception or some other way. Is it possible?

I think I could query if there are activities suitable for my original intent using [`queryIntentActivities()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). Would that be a good solution? Would it be too slow to use it on the UI thread? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I could query if there are activities suitable for my original intent using queryIntentActivities(). Would that be a good solution?

Sure. If that returns an empty list, you know the chooser will not have any options.

> Would it be too slow to use it on the UI thread?

Not that I am aware of.

> Is there a better way?

Have someone else write the call to `queryIntentActivities()` for you, while you relax. :-)